# Getting file format by checking file header

Tags: c, refactoring, file-handling, headers, file-formats

I'm writing a program, part of which consists of determining if a given file is a PNG. Knowing that a file doesn't have to be named with its respective filename extension to be of a certain type, I decided to check for it's header. However, after not being able to think of anything better, I wrote this if statement with loads of `&&`...

```
uint8_t buffer[sizeof(uint8_t) * size];
int fileType;

if (fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t) * size, 1, fp) == 1) {

    if (buffer[0] == 137 && buffer[1] == 80  &&
            buffer[2] == 78  && buffer[3] == 71  &&
            buffer[4] == 13  && buffer[5] == 10  &&
            buffer[6] == 26  && buffer[7] == 10) 
                fileType = PNG;

}
```

`size` has been determined before and `PNG` is from an `enum` type, in case there's any confusion.

I tried having the header bits of the PNG file format as a macro, but it seemed much too complicated (because of the way they are read onto a buffer) to check if the given file's bits are the same as that macro. I also tried using strings, but it also seemed much more complicated than this.

I was wondering, how would you go about refactoring this? Or, since there probably is a better way, how else could I check if the PNG header is present in a given file?

Comment: Why not just use libpng or similar to try to open it instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @whatsisname I guess this is what happens when someone doesn't know that the wheel exists. I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `memcmp` to compare the PNG header against the first bytes of the file. Other than that you can't avoid opening and reading the file.

Maybe you should `fseek` back to the start, to reset the file descriptor offset.